Linker Error When Linking GLAD with OpenGL and GLFW in CMake/MSBuild
I'm working on an OpenGL project using GLFW and GLAD in a CMake-based setup:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)  # Specify the project name and the languages
project(MyApp LANGUAGES CXX)

# Set C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Include directories
include_directories(MyApp PUBLIC 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Resources
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Shaders
)

# Add executable
add_executable(MyApp  
    main.cpp
    stb.cpp
    folder/File.cpp
)

# Link libraries
target_link_libraries(MyApp PRIVATE 
    opengl32.lib
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/lib/glfw3.lib
)

...and I'm encountering a linker error related to GLAD:
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__gladLoaderLoadGL

I've configured the project to use GLAD with OpenGL, and I'm able to build the GLFW library through Vcpkg successfully.
I've verified that GLAD is installed and properly included in the project. However, the linking still fails. I also tried manually including the glad.c file in the project, but the issue persists.
Why am I getting the unresolved external symbol error and how to properly link GLAD with my OpenGL project?

Recommendation: Get the glad.c experiment out of the cmakelists file. Some people will focus unnecessarily on it and write ed-up answers and comments.

I just removed it from the cmakelist file and it's still the same

Apologies. I meant remove it from the question here. The closer your example gets to the "correct" approach, the less likely folks are going to grasp onto a mistake you may have added while shotgun-debugging. Not that you should shotgun-debug in the first place, but welcome to our messy reality.

Do you know if ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/lib/glfw3.lib is a static library or a stub to make it easier to load a DLL? The __imp_ in front to the symbol name tells the linker "Get the symbol from a DLL!", so if you have a static library, it'll be missing the __imp_.

Could u elabore more on stub or static library please?

Some lib files contain enough code to tell the program to load the function from a DLL. This is what I mean by stub. The stub doesn't really do anything; the actual implementation is somewhere else. The statically linked library contains the implementation directly. I might have been off base on removing glad.c, but regardless, something in your setup is looking for gladLoaderLoadGL inside a DLL, not in a directly linked object file or static library.

in my main.cpp file am calling gladLoaderLoadGL to check if glad was initialized successfuly

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

And main.cpp is compiling, so it finds a declaration in a header. Out there, somewhere, there is a library that matches the header and contains the symbol. We're just having trouble finding it. Say... do you have a glad.lib or anything like it?

i have only a lib file and that would be glfw3.lib in the lib directory of the project. also opengl32.lib but thats from the system

I can find gladLoadGLLoader in glad.c, but not gladLoaderLoadGL. This is looking damn peculiar. I'm an embedded systems guy, and this is getting pretty far out of my wheelhouse.  I'm going to have to shut up and leave this to the experts at this point.

Actually it is indeed gladLoadGLLoader ```error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol gladLoadGLLoader referenced in the function main


That one doesn't have the __imp_prefix. You should be able to solve that one by compiling and linking in glad.c. Effed if I know where gladLoaderLoadGLcomes from.

"I've verified that glad is installed and properly included in the project." - Eh? I see no line in your CMakeLists.txt which adds glad or links with it.

The issue stemmed from several oversights in the project setup. The language for the project wasn't explicitly defined as C and CXX. This omission caused confusion about the build process and glad was not properly linked as a static library, and its C language specification was missing, leading to compatibility issues.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

# Specify the project name and languages
project(ShaderToy LANGUAGES C CXX)

# Set C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Include directories
include_directories(
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Resources
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Shaders
)

# Add glad as a library and specify its language
add_library(glad STATIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/glad.c)
set_target_properties(glad PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)

# Add executable
add_executable(ShaderToy 
    main.cpp
    stb.cpp
    Shaders/shaderClass.cpp
)

# Link glad, GLFW, and OpenGL
target_link_libraries(ShaderToy PRIVATE 
    glad
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/lib/glfw3.lib 
    opengl32.lib
)

